# Combine xarray Dataset variables along a new dimension without expanding each one

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray with dimensions lat and lon. It includes 17 variables, each one corresponding with a different time step. I would like to expand the dimensions to include time and reduce the number of variables to only one, with 17 time steps. I've tried implementing this with the following code, but I end up with n variables, with each variable including all the time steps and lat, long dimensions.

The original dataset, ds:
[image: ds]

```
all_dates = ['2019-03-29','2019-05-10','2019-06-21','2019-07-19','2019-08-30','2019-10-11','2019-11-22','2020-01-03','2020-02-14','2020-03-27','2020-05-08','2020-06-19','2020-07-17','2020-08-28','2020-10-09','2021-10-08','2021-11-19']

date_list = pd.to_datetime(all_dates)
ds2 = ds.expand_dims(time=date_list)
```

The new dataset includes an array of 17 timesteps for each data variable, instead of one data variable with 17 time steps: [image: ds2]

Is there a way to add a time dimension, and reduce the dataset's n variables to include a single variable corresponding with the n time steps in the time dimension?

Comment: great question! I clarified your question title a bit so others with a similar problem might find it too.

Comment: Great, thanks, that does make it a lot clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`xr.Dataset.to_array`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_array.html). [`expand_dims`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.expand_dims.html) does exactly what it's doing in your post - it copies *each array in your data* so that they each include the full time dimnension. But you're essentially looking to concatenate all arrays into a single one *along* the new dimension.

```py
# concatenate the arrays, assign the name "all_images", return to a Dataset,
# and assign the time dimension
ds.to_array("time", name="all_images").to_dataset().assign_coords(
    time=date_list
)
```

You could also do this with [`xr.concat`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html) by pulling out each array and concatenating them. Using concat may be a more careful method to ensure the correct ordering since you're relabeling your arrays.

```py
# concatenate each image with an explicit order while assigning
# them the coordinate from date_list
xr.concat(
    [ds[f"image{i}" for i in range(1, len(date_list) + 1)],
    dim=pd.Index(date_list, name="time"),
).to_dataset(name="all_images")
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and excellent response! That was exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate it.

Comment: glad it helped! and happy xarray-ing :)